# User Defined Interface vs Built In Interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

Based on its understanding, in Java, interface is a group of related methods with empty body. Each class that implement interface, should provide the implementation, of each method found in the interface.

But there are some built in interface, that its method, has its implementation already, and ready to be used. For example: Interface Enumeration. It has 2 methods, that are ready to be used, such as hasMoreElements() and nextElement(). 
Refer to the link below: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_enumeration_interface.htm

Based on the interface understanding, interface consist only method with empty body, but why Interface Enumeration, can consist method with implementation ...

Please kindly explain ...

Comment: They are not "ready to be used". In the example you're referring to `Vector` has them implemented, not `Enumeration`. So `Vector` *implements* the `Enumeration` interface.

Comment: Vector doesn't implement Enumeration. Vector's `elements()` method returns an instance of a class which implements Enumeration. Call `System.out.println(vector.elements().getClass())`, and you'll see the actual name of the class which implements Enumeration.

Comment: An object that implements an interface, say `Enumeration`, is-a `Enumeration`. When you declare a reference to an `Enumeration` you have access to the underlying class's *implementation* of that interface.

Comment: I think this is a good question. The implements keyword that we use to implement the functionality of a user-defined interface is the implements keyword that we use to take advantage of pre-implemented built-in interfaces, making interfaces seem like 2 things at once: a magic trick and a coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

You got that wrong.

You are not using the direct interface methods. The Vector class implemented the Enumeration and provided the implementation. Those methods are getting executed.

You can see the evidance here in the line

```
  Enumeration days= dayNames.elements();
```

The method `elements()` in Vector returns the Enumeration instance implemented  inside Vector.

[See the source code of Vector class here,](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.elements%28%29) You can see the implementation provided .

Comment: Here I have link related to vector: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html  The link consist of list of method the vector has, but inside the list got no Enumeration method.

Comment: Some more, if vector has the implementation of enumeration method already, why then not use the method directly, instead of submitting the object to Enumeration variable.

Comment: @user1980576 That is called as Programming to interfaces :) Google that.